# Return Hex Color code with SASS lighten function

Tags: css, sass

How do I return a hex code using the SASS lighten function?

```
@function returnHexValue($color){
    @debug $color;
    @if $color == "white" {
        @return "#fff";
    }
    @if $color == "black" {
        @return "#000";
    }
    @return $color;
}
```

When I use something like `returnHexValue(lighten(#000,100%));`, I still get the value returned as `white` instead of `#fff`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following function that will force Hex value

```
@function force-hex($color) {
    @if type-of($color) == 'color' {
        $hex: str-slice(ie-hex-str($color), 4);
        @return unquote("\##{$hex}");
    }
    @return $color;
}

body{
  color: force-hex(lighten(#000,100%));
}
```

Already there are few request in SASS github project to prevent conversion of Hex to a color value. You can follow below issues

https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/343
https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/363